# Add static data to dynamically created ListView that uses a ListAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, listadapter

I'd like to add X number of static rows to a ListView that is uses a ListAdapter/BaseAdapter to dynamically populate the ListView currently. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance, Cole.

**My Solution**: per @Femi's suggestions, I ended up using a MergeAdapter. Here's a snippet of what I did:

```
    // create a new MergeAdapter
    MergeAdapter aMergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();

    // add the dynamic content
    SkipToListActivityValueAdapter skipToListActivityValueAdapter = 
        new SkipToListActivityValueAdapter(this, sections);
    aMergeAdapter.addAdapter(skipToListActivityValueAdapter);

    // add the static content
    ArrayAdapter<String> aArrayAdapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ADDITIONAL_SKIP_TO_OPTIONS);
    aMergeAdapter.addAdapter(aArrayAdapter);

    // add the aMergeAdapter to the ListAdapter
    setListAdapter(aMergeAdapter);
```

Comment: Atleast show your code.Show what have you done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the MergeAdapter, by @commonsware. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge for details, but incredibly handy piece of code for heterogenous data sources. You can stitch together multiple adapters and Views quite nicely in whatever order you want.

Comment: great! i'm importing the .jar now. i'll let you know how it goes! thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Good to know it worked. In my case I made the parent Activity implement `android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;` and then set that as the `ListView` listener (I wasn't using `ListActivity`). Then I implemented `onItemClick` and that worked.

Comment: got it - i just added additional if's for the positions of the static rows i added. duh!